# Moving Active jobs in a Shell from the Background to Foreground and the Other Way Around

Tags: c

[This section](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Access-to-the-Terminal.html#Access-to-the-Terminal) of the glibc manual explains job control, but unless I am missing it, it doesn't explain how to implement the ability to move a job that has already launched into the background or foreground.

Can anyone give me a basic example, overview, or a link that explains how this works?

I don't mean how to do this in a shell, but rather how to implement it when writing a shell.

Comment: "tcsetpgrp() will set the foreground process group ID associated with the terminal"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two aspects of foreground/background in the Posix *nix operating systems.

One is absurdly simple: the shell or some other parent process either *is* or *is not* waiting (via some variation on `wait(2)`) for the child to finish. If the parent is waiting, it's foreground. If it's not, it's background. In the original versions of *nix, this was the entire story. As you can see, the shell actually did *less* work to implement the magic `% command &` pattern than just `% command`, yet few other systems could do this.

Now, that leaves a few loose ends. Processes have controlling terminals and terminals have process groups. There are session leaders and process group leaders. It is nice to have signals directed simultaneously at just, say, one connected pipeline in the background. Jobs in the background that attempt terminal I/O get a signal.  When users log out the OS may want to reclaim a virtual or physical terminal for security and in order to give the next user unobstructed access. So the entire story gets rather more complex. `4.1BSD` introduced essentially the present-day full-blown job control mechanism.

I've given you the keywords to search for if you want to know at a more detailed level than this.

Comment: I kind of got that much ( nice summary though ).  More specifically, I think what I am most confused about how I would 'cancel' the wait that is blocking for the foreground job to move into the background (Handle Ctrl-Z).

Comment: Basically, the implementation of fg %jobid or bg %jobid commands.

Comment: The fg, I think I have.  I just return the process group to the foreground and do a block wait on it.

Comment: Oh, sorry! We get a lot of really basic questions, but rereading yours I should have realized you were writing a shell. I think you are correct about fg. For bg, I believe you trap `SIGTSTP` using `sigaction()` without specifying `SA_RESTART`. Then, you return from the trap handler to the `wait*()` call, which will will cause the `wait*()` to return with EINTR, because you did not give `SA_RESTART` to `sigaction()`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I can just add WUNTRACED and it will block until the job is stopped or it terminates...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be a smart ass, but have you tried looking in:

http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/bash-4.0.tar.gz

;-)

-Oisin